# User Can't Reset Password

Tags: 7

I am very new in Drupal and still building site.

- So, I want to test creating new user by clicking on below.

[image: Creating new user]

---

---

- Entering new username and e-mail address.

[image: Entering username and email address]

---

---

- Redirect to site's home and got this successful message.

[image: Redirect and success message]

---

---

- I login as admin and activate the user.

[image: Activate user]

---

---

- I got the confirmation email and click the link sent there to reset user password.

[image: Tap reset password link]

---

---

- Then tapping on login button, redirect me to this:

[image: Weird!]

---

---

Why does this message appears?

> You have tried to use a one-time login link that has either been used
>   or is no longer valid. Please request a new one using the form below.

It seems that the system can't remember that the reset link must be still in function. Is there any fix for this that I don't need to connect to Drupal's server remotely?

Comment: Do you have any errors in Drupal's watchdog or server's error logs? It seems like the one-time login key is simply not saved. Or maybe you have some redirects set up?

Comment: Hi @Mołot , this is weird, now it works as expected ~_~ . Seeing from the log reports in my Drupal web console, it starts working since the 'Cron run completed' . So, I suspect maybe the cron was the problem. Btw, before that, there is no error mentioning resetting things.

Comment: Glad it worked. Maybe some cache tables was full, or something, and cron dealt with it? Consider installing Elysia Cron and playing with it a bitt.

Comment: Yeah maybe there was something blocking up the system to remember user's session. Elysian Cron seems good, I will use it for my other site. Thanks @Mołot !

Comment: Hi @Mołot now the problem comes back, but this time it's more weird. Upon clicking the Login button, now the user logged in to the site and never can be logged out, also, the error above appears again..

Comment: What's in your sessions table? What if you truncate it?

Comment: Still doesn't give any result. I give up by installing new module in my site to skip the one time login button..

Comment: I have same question
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/118592/reset-password-form-does-not-let-user-enter-their-new-password