# Reset Password Form does not let user enter their new password

Tags: 7, users

1. An regular registered user reset a password
2. An email with one-time link will sent to the user
3. Clicking the link will lead the user to the change password form
4. Now, the drupal site warn the user the link has been used. The user need to get another one-time link.
5. Cannot enter the reset form

Comment: There's something wrong in the workflow you describe. The one-time link will take the user to his edit form allowing the user to change the password. Check there's no redirection. Also, try use the link with /login at the end (without this /login Drupal offers a page after really use the link and log in the user)

Comment: @tunic I see. let me re-describe it.

Comment: One time passwords are invalidated after a certain time and after user has loged in. Double check your are not triggering one of this conditions or you are generating the link in a different server where the links points (this can happen whe using different dev servers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by installed the [Simple Password Reset](https://drupal.org/project/simple_pass_reset) module:

> Without this module enabled, core Drupal prompts the user to log in
>   via a one-time login form. After clicking "Log in", the user is
>   brought to their profile edit form where at long last they can change
>   their password.
>
> With this module enabled, the user skips the one-time login form.
>   Instead the password reset link brings them right to the profile edit
>   form where they can immediately change their password and log in. So
>   what core Drupal does in two steps, this module does in one.